# C# & unity: error CS0103: The name 'Utilities' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, scripting, static

This is my first post so please go easy on me.

I'm following a tutorial document on C# related with Unity.

I created a script and class called Utilities:

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    
    public static class Utilities
    {
        public static int playerDeaths = 0;
        public static void RestartLevel()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
            Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
        }
    }
```

When I tried to use this class, in another script unity, it throws me the error above:

```cs
    private void OnGUI()
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(20, 20, 150, 25), "Player Health: " + _playerHP);
            GUI.Box(new Rect(20, 50, 150, 25), "Items Collected: " + _itemsCollected);
            GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height - 50, 300, 50), labelText);
    
            if (showLossScreen)
            {
                if (GUI.Button(new Rect (Screen.width /2 -100,Screen.height /2-50,200,100), "You Lose..."))
                {
                   Utilities.RestartLevel();
                }
            }
```

I read somewhere about an update and/or start method being involved.

I'm at lost, please help me out.

Comment: In general using `OnGUI` (IMGUI) is pretty legacy! You should rather use the ["new" UI Package (uGUI)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.ugui.html) or the newest [UI Toolkit](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-UITK-package.html)

Comment: Are your two scripts in the same folder? If you click on the scripts in Unity once in the Inspector what do they say in [`Assembly Information`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html#find-assembly)?

Comment: and you havent put that second code in a namespace?

Comment: @ derHugo, says file name (assembly c#. dl)??? but no destination folder... also says no mono scripts in file or file name does not match class name???

Comment: i just deleted the script and re pasted the code and the script name is exactly the same, and now it works... right

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @tec9blues, I would advice to include more information in your question because it too broad. What is the tutorial you are talking about? Do you know the purposed of the code you believe has the issue? Are there any error or exception logs that you could include to help you out?